# Priming before workshops so people choose to be more empathetic during empathy mapping

Tags: psychology, workshop, priming

We do a lot of workshops and kickoffs with clients. One of the exercises we do is [empathy mapping](http://www.cooper.com/journal/2014/5/persona-empathy-mapping) of their potential customers.

Are there any suggested [priming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)) activities that would help people [choose to be more empathetic](https://www.edge.org/conversation/jamil_zaki-choosing-empathy) during exercises? It could be an explicit activity or something that they don't know is priming before they start.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the participants into the mindset of potential customers by using foto stories, storybooks, videos, or others.

After this anchor you could try [body storming](https://www.mycoted.com/Bodystorming), [role stroming](https://www.mycoted.com/RoleStorming) or [take other peoples viewpoint](https://www.mycoted.com/Other_Peoples_Viewpoints) to get input for the empathy map.

Actually these are creativity techniques used by actors to tune in their role.